# Making exported variables stick around in bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell

I have 2 scripts, one.sh and two.sh

one.sh triggers a call to two.sh which internally sources/runs other scripts. I want to use variables exported in two.sh to stick around and use them in one.sh

```
one.sh:

#!/bin/bash
. ./path/two.sh
echo "VAR: $VAR"

--------------

two.sh

#!/bin/bash

#source/run other .sh scripts
. $(dirname "$0")/../three.sh

export VAR="hello"
```

When I run one.sh it allows me to use the var "VAR" but throws an error for the scripts that are being internally sourced or run within two.sh:

**./path/two.sh: line 3: ./../three.sh: No such file or directory**

If I change one.sh to the following:

```
one.sh
#!/bin/bash
./path/two.sh --> removed the "." in front of ./path/two.sh
echo "VAR: $VAR"

output: ./one.sh
VAR:    ===> NOT EXPORTED
```

Is there a way that allows me to export variables in two.sh and use them in one.sh and also lets me trigger/source other scripts in two.sh
Apologies if this seems a little too basic but I looked around for similar questions and didnt find one

Comment: In two.sh, don't you just need to assign the variable *before* sourcing the other scripts?

Comment: Have a look at the difference between sourcing and executing a script : https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the lines int `two.sh` that look like:

```
. $(dirname "$0")/../three.sh
```

This tries to locate `three.sh` relative to the location of the script currently being executed.  But, merely sourcing a script doesn't count.  When `one.sh` sources `two.sh`, the value of `$0` still refers to `one.sh`.

I see two reasonable solutions:

1. Move one.sh to the two.sh's directory.  That way the relative paths to source files in two.sh will still work.

   Or:
2. Remove from `two.sh` all references to `$(dirname "$0")/`.  Instead provide explicit paths.

Comment: Thank you @John1024.
Your comment about it uses the relative path from the location of script executed currently cleared for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The first version of "one.sh" is OK. But in the "two.sh" script, if you run "dirname $0", it always returns ".". This makes that the path to the "three.sh" could be invalid. I recommend you change:

```
#source/run other .sh scripts
. $(dirname "$0")/../three.sh
```

for this:

```
#source/run other .sh scripts
. $(readlink -f $(dirname "$0"))/../three.sh
```

or by this:

```
#source/run other .sh scripts
. $(pwd)/../three.sh
```

In this case the two answers are correct by I prefer the first becasuse if "two.sh" runs a "cd" commands it will work too.